# Solving sets involving equations $\text{{z | $ 3z = n^ 2$, z and n are natural numbers}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve the following sets:

$\text{  {y  |  $2y^2$= 50,  y is an integer}  }$

So as I understand this means: $y$ such that $2y^2 = 50$ and $y$ is and integer.

I tried to solve it this way:

I re-arranged the equation $2y^2= 50$ to solve for  $y$ and I got this: $y^2 = 25$ then I tried to find integer values for $y$ so that it'll be equal to 25; the values are 5 and -5: so the set is $\{5, -5\}$.

The other one seems a little more trickier:

$\text{{z | $ 3z = n^ 2$, z and n are natural numbers}}$

so I followed the same steps which I used to solve the first problem above:

I first re-arranged the equation: $ 3z = n^ 2$ to $z = n^2/3$

*Now I don't know what to do next and I'm not sure if the method that I use here to solve these problems are correct?

The last one is: 
$\text{ {x | x = 2n - 5, x and n are natural numbers} }$

The equation here: $x = 2n - 5$

**I don't get how should I interpret/solve these problems?**

Comment: For the second set, consider this: $n^2$ is a perfect square and 3z is a multiple of 3. Hence you are really finding all perfect squares which are divisible by 3. And for the third set, you have $2n - 5 = x$ as an natural number. We know that $2n-5$ is an integer for sure, but what restrictions is needed for it to be a natural number?

Comment: @thedilated _"For the second set, consider this: $n^2$ is a perfect square and $3z$ is a multiple of 3. Hence you are really finding all perfect squares which are divisible by 3."_. Therefore: $\text{ {z| $z = n^2 / 3$, z and n are natural numbers} }$ which is the set $\{3, 12, 27...\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeaps you're right! :)

Answer (score 1):

$3z=n^2\implies\ n$ must be a multiple of $3\implies 3z=\{9k^2\ |k\in\mathbb{N}\}\implies z=\{3k^2\ |k\in\mathbb{N}\}$

$x=\{2n-5 |n\in \mathbb{N}\}\ x$ is also a natural number so $2n-5\ge 1\implies n\ge3\ \therefore x=\{2n-5|n\in\mathbb{N},n\ge 3\}$

Comment: Alright, $\text{ {z | $ 3z = n^ 2 $, z and n are natural numbers} }$ will be the set $z = \{3, 12, 27...\}$. I depend on  this method as I mentioned above, I transformed $ 3z = n^ 2 $ into $z = n^2/3$ and then I substituted $n^2$ with natural numbers starting from 1...N; then I check if the value of z is natural or not. For example, let's substitute $n$ with 6 which is a natural number: $z = 6^2/3 = 12$ so both $n$ and $z$ are natural numbers, as such I can write 12 in the set of $z$. **Is this one right way to solve it? Not necessarily the most efficient one, just right!**